# Why statement doesn't return result

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to get object from table `Type`, but query returns empty ResultSet:

```
public Type get(String id) {
    Type type = null;

    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append("SELECT * FROM ");
    queryBuilder.append(TABLE_NAME);
    queryBuilder.append(" WHERE ");
    queryBuilder.append(TYPE + "=?;");
    String query = queryBuilder.toString();

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if(result.next()){
            type = new Type(id,
                    result.getString(DEFINITION));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return type;
}
```

TABLE_NAME and TYPE are "Type" and "type".

if I try query in MySQL console with same arguments, it will return result. What's wrong?

Comment: Well are any exceptions being thrown? Just printing the stack trace and then returning `null` probably isn't what you want to do - I'd probably just declare that the method throws `SQLException`. Next, which column of the table are you trying to get? Given that you only want one column, why not specify that in your query? What's `DEFINITION`? Have you debugged into the code to see whether `result.next()` returns true or not?

Comment: If you'd include some DATA for your table we could maybe see something.

Comment: Try to remove semicolon here ;

  queryBuilder.append(TYPE + "=?;");

Comment: OK, i have understood, that problem is with using non-latin characters in query. Also, may be problem is because i used ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; for creating table and primary key type is varchar?